# If React Component Library needs React as a peer dependency, how can I make Preact using it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

Suppose I have a React Component library called `myLibrary`.

`myLibrary` has exported a `<Hello />` Component:

```
import React from 'react';

function Hello() {
  return <div>World</div>
}
```

And `myLibrary`'s package.json specific `React` as a peer dependency.

Which means it doesn't install `React` when I npm install it in my other project.

How can I use `myLibrary` in my preact project without installing React?

In my preact project:

`yarn add myLibrary`

```
// main.js
/** @jsx h */
import { Hello } from 'myLibrary';
import { h, render } from 'preact';

render(<Hello />, document.body);
```

How can I make it all happen without installing `React`?

Comment: Are you aliasing react to `preact/compat` anywhere?

Comment: No, I think I should do that.

Comment: @JosephWang did you ever end up solving this issue?

Comment: @elethan I think preact-compat is the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is what preact-compat is for! You'll want to implement per the readme here: https://github.com/developit/preact-compat